# Problems with onscroll function executing multiple conditional statements

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, onscroll

I have a JavaScript function that executes different conditional statements when the window is scrolled to certain points.

(More or less changing the style of my nav-links when the window is scrolled into a new section/row)

```
// variables used
var pLink = document.getElementById('p-link');

var rLink = document.getElementById('r-link');

var bLink = document.getElementById('b-link');

var cLink = document.getElementById('c-link');

var pElement = document.getElementById('slide');

var row2 = document.getElementById('row-2')

var pHeader = document.getElementById('p-header');

//function starts here

window.onscroll = function() {scrollLink() };
function scrollLink() {

/* 
when the top of the window scrolls to the top of the page (within 100):
the background color of row-2 (and the color of its text elements) revert back to their original styles 
*/

if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
} else {
        document.getElementById('row-2').style.backgroundColor = "#5e312b";
        document.getElementById('p-header').style.color = "#fff";
        pElement.style.color = "#fff";

/*
when the top of the window scrolls to a certain point (past 450):
slide() is executed (text animation - moves from left to center)
*/

} if (document.body.scrollTop > 450 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 450) {
        slide();

/* 
when the top of the window scrolls into row-2 (past 692):
the color of the nav links changes from pink to white and the opacity of the nav links (except portfolio) is reduced
this change is needed for visibility (when bgChange1 is executed - the background turns pink) 
when the top of the window scrolls back into row-1 (past 692 in the other direction):
the color and opacity of the nav links reverts back to their original style
*/

} if (document.body.scrollTop > 692 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 692) {
        pLink.style.color = "#fff";
        rLink.style.color = "#fff";
        bLink.style.color = "#fff";
        cLink.style.color = "#fff";
        rLink.style.opacity = ".6";
        bLink.style.opacity = ".6";
        cLink.style.opacity = ".6";
}   else {
        pLink.style.color = "#D07F8D";
        rLink.style.color = "#D07F8D";
        bLink.style.color = "#D07F8D";
        cLink.style.color = "#D07F8D";
        rLink.style.opacity = "1";
        bLink.style.opacity = "1";
        cLink.style.opacity = "1";
}
};
```

The function as it is above works fine.

However, when I try to add the last conditional statement (below), the function stops working properly. Not only does the new conditional statement not execute, but it screws up the previously working function (above).

```
/*
when the top of the window scrolls into row-3 (past 1800):
the color of the nav links changes to pink
this change is needed for visibility (the previous if statement styled the links white - hard to see against row-3's background)
when the top of the windows scrolls back into row-2 (past 1800 in the other directon):
the color and opacity of the nav links reverts back to their style in row-2
*/

if (document.body.scrollTop > 1800 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1800) {
        pLink.style.color = "#D07F8D";
        rLink.style.color = "#D07F8D";
        bLink.style.color = "#D07F8D";
        cLink.style.color = "#D07F8D";
        pLink.style.opacity = ".5";
        bLink.style.opacity = ".5";
        cLink.style.opacity = ".5";
} else {
        pLink.style.color = "#fff";
        rLink.style.color = "#fff";
        bLink.style.color = "#fff";
        cLink.style.color = "#fff";
        pLink.style.opacity = "1";
        bLink.style.opacity = "1";
        cLink.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because your ifs are all treated separately and not written somehow using `else if`. So every time the function runs it always hits the `else` statement of the last one you added.

When `if (document.body.scrollTop > 1800 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1800) {` is false which is anytime its not greater than that it runs the else statement which sets everything back to white and full opacity.

In other words this if block stands alone. So any previous style changes you have made will be overwritten every time since it will always enter one of these blocks.

```
if (document.body.scrollTop > 1800 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1800) {
        pLink.style.color = "#D07F8D";
        rLink.style.color = "#D07F8D";
        bLink.style.color = "#D07F8D";
        cLink.style.color = "#D07F8D";
        pLink.style.opacity = ".5";
        bLink.style.opacity = ".5";
        cLink.style.opacity = ".5";
} else {
        pLink.style.color = "#fff";
        rLink.style.color = "#fff";
        bLink.style.color = "#fff";
        cLink.style.color = "#fff";
        pLink.style.opacity = "1";
        bLink.style.opacity = "1";
        cLink.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

Perhaps you could add return statements in each if to stop subsequent ifs from running after you have set styles.